# Specify the first post in while loop by taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop, posts

I'm trying to query posts in wordpress, so far so good. However, I would like to show a post with a specific tag 'info' in front of all (even in front of sticky).

Now the query of the theme is like this:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    rsort( $sticky );

    if(of_get_option('sticky-posts') == 'show_sticky'){         

        query_posts (array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'order' => $order_posts,  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) ); 



    }
```

And after that the loop starts:

```
//BEGIN LOOP
    //=====================================================?> 

    <article id="articlehold">


        <?php


        if(have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Now I've done some editing in the query to get the post with the 'info' tag in front, but no luck. Now I'm not sure where the best place is to edit this, in the loop or before the loop?

How could I do this?

Comment: You can't use a `WP_Query` object like this mainly because the SQL operator has no idea how to handle that comparison and return it to you. As such, you'll need to use `usort()` and sort the array before actually iterating it.

Comment: Okay.. it's now ordered Ascending also (set by a theme option: $order_posts). Not sure if this mixes it up too. Is it not possible to make 2 queries? First with the specific post tag and then the rest? In that order?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use multiple queries, but then you're creating needlessly excessive SQL queries causing the CPU usage on your server to raise and consuming more of the available MySQL Processes. If you're on shared hosting, this may become problematic one day. It would be best to sort the returned array instead as previously mentioned using `usort()`

Comment: Well it arent that many posts to query so that wouldn't be a problem. However. Could you give an example how to sort the returned array? If I could get the post id's in the right order, I propably get it worked out.